# Real Time search in Orkut - (like twitter)

Tags: opensocial

Does the OpenSocial or any other API allow access such that we can get real time updates of what users are scrapping about on Orkut ?

For e.g. much like I can query twitter on what people are feeling about a movie or a book, I want to do the same with orkut ?

At the moment I can go into Orkut - do a search , click on Topics in search result and sort of get the information - I just want to be able to do this through the API !

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such API for Orkut in this moment.